# Maximum likelihood in R with mle and fitdistr

Tags: r, estimation, mle

I have a problem with maximum likelihood in R, that I hope you can help me with. In the code Nt stands for observed claims counts and vt for corresponding volumes.

First I assume a Poisson dist. so I have estimated lambda with mle and got 0.10224. Then I tried to estimate lambda with fitdistr, and the result was 1022.4. How come it is a difference between these two functions? How do I correct it?

Later I tried, with the same data, to estimate the parameters of a Negative binomial. But I haven't got it to work. Can you see what I have done wrong? The start values for lambda and gamma are just random numbers I picked.

```
library(stats4)
library(MASS) 

Nt <- c(1000, 997, 985, 989, 1056, 1070, 994, 986, 1093, 1054)
vt <- rep(10000, 10) 
n <- length(Nt)

obs.freq <- Nt/vt
overall.freq <- sum(Nt)/sum(vt)

#####
# mle - poisson
#####

fit.poisson <- function(lamda){
-sum(dpois(Nt, lamda*vt, log=TRUE))
}

mle.poisson <- mle(fit.poisson, start=list(lamda=overall.freq), nobs = NROW(Nt))
mle.poisson.summary <- summary(mle.poisson)

fitdistr(Nt, "Poisson")   

#####
# mle - negative binomial
#####

fit.negbin <- function(lamda, gamma){
SUM <- numeric(n)
for(i in 1:n){
SUM[i] <- lfactorial(Nt[i]+gamma-1) - lfactorial(Nt[i]) - lfactorial(gamma-1) + gamma*log(1-lamda*vt[i]/(gamma+lamda*vt[i])) + Nt[i]*log(lamda*vt[i]/(gamma+lamda*vt[i]))
}
-sum(SUM)
}

mle.negbin <- mle(fit.negbin, start=list(lamda=0.1, gamma=2), nobs=n)
mle.negbin.summary <- summary(mle.negbin)

fitdistr(Nt,"Negative binomial")
```

Answer (score 0):

In your first attempt using `mle()`, you are incorporating `vt` while in your `fitdistr()` attempt, you are not. You can get the same result by either changing `fit.poisson` to just:

```
fit.poisson <- function(lamda){
    -sum(dpois(Nt, lambda, log=TRUE))
}
```

or by changing your `fitdistr()` to:

```
fitdistr(Nt/vt, "Poisson")
```

I don't see anything wrong with your negative binomial model. The lambda estimate from the negative binomial model (0.10197) is pretty close to the lambda estimate in the Poisson model (0.10224).